# Proof: the tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

Suppose we need to prove that a tangent $t$ at point $P$ of a circle $\Lambda(O;r)$ is perpendicular to $OP$.
Proof: Drop a perpendicular $OX$ from the center $O$ on $t$. Since for any point $Q \neq X$ on $t$, $\Delta OQX$ is a right-angled triangle, we must get $OX<OQ$ for $\angle OXQ=90^{0}$. This also holds for $Q=P$ if we assume that $OP$ is not perpendicular to $t$(or assume that $X\neq P$). Thus, we will have $OX<OP=r$ for $Q=P$. Note that $X$ must now lie inside the circle. But since $X,P\in t$ and two distinct points must determine a line, $XP$ must coincide with $t$. Also,if $\angle OPX=\alpha$, taking $180-2\alpha$ at center O and initial ray OP, the intersection point of $XP$ and the terminal ray of the angle, $M$ lies on the circle(M is another common point of t and the circle). But $t$ is a tangent to the circle. Thus, we get a contradiction. Thus, $X$ must coincide with $P$. Thus, OP is perpendicular to t.

Is this proof legit and without any gaps?

Comment: Please find a more useful and informative title.

Comment: What definition of a tangent to a circle do you use?

Comment: Euclides: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII18.html

Comment: A tangent is a line that intersects the circle at only one point.-This definition.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Shogo Makishima,

We can prove that a tangent is perpendicular to the radius of a circle. Let's say we have a circle C(O,r) where O is the center and r is the radius. Then a tangent is drawn anywhere on the circle. Let's define the tangent as AB. A Tangent is a line that touches a single point on the circle. So where the tangent touches the circle we draw the radius. Since now every line is greater than the radius if we draw a line from the center we can say the radius is the shortest distance from the circle. Then we apply the theorem: The perpendicular is the shortest distance from a given line. From this theorem, we can say that radius is perpendicular to the tangent.